# Why gravitational potential is same?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, symmetry, potential-energy, gauss-law

Why is the gravitational potential at the surface of a hollow sphere equal to the gravitational potential inside the sphere which is $-\frac {Gm}{r}$ ? Does this mean that the potential is the same at every place inside the sphere?

N.B > The hollow sphere generates the Gravitational field

Comment: how lengthy and detailed answer are you looking for?  this shell theorem can be found in textbooks and wikis, so probably that is a good place to look for. in case you look for something else, let me know.

Comment: If you help me with both figure and details it would be helpful . Yeah I saw some books but some critical theories they mentioned that I am not familiar with .

Comment: In my answer, I gave you this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem#Inside_a_shell , where you can find a a nice figure that explains it. Would be harder for me to draw something better than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, inside the hollow shell the potential is the same anywhere, thus the net gravitational force on a test mass inside the shell is zero. This the famous **shell theorem** of classical gravitation theory, which is explained in many textbooks (see for a description at this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem#Inside_a_shell)). The reason for this is basically [Gauss's flux theorem for gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity).